# Awk Sed find and assign results to multiple variables

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have to read a large file and find the occurrences of FamlyType. Once I find that, I need to assign what's under the faimlytype sections  under which there are number of data points that I need to assign to variables for me to do further testing ..

```
FamilyType

FamilyKind              String      G
userName:               String:     MATT_HANS
serviceList:           String:         H2O
hostList:               String:     159.220.108.80
protocol:               String:         UDP
portNumber:             Numeric:        8149
port:                  String:      TCPIP


FamilyType

FamilyKind              String      f
userName:               String:     Geroge_lucas
serviceList:           String:      WWW
hostList:               String:     159.220.108.70
protocol:               String:     TCP
portNumber:             Numeric:    8166
port:                  String:      TCPIP
```

SO I need to write a routine in my script to find the Familtype then assign username & servicelist & hoslist and portNumebrto variables 
So result should be

Please note there are lots of leading spaces before each variable

```
userName1="MATT_HANS"
serviceList1="H2O"
hostList1:"159.220.108.80"
portNumber1="8149"

userName2="Geroge_lucas"
serviceList2="WWW"
hostList2:"159.220.108.70"
portNumber2="8166"
```

I am using Bounre shell / Bash
Is it possible to user sed or awk to do this in one run? If you offer any help, please explain the command; so i can use it in future as well

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow isn't a free coding service. You're expected to show an effort in writing your own code. When you get stuck, then you can show your input, required output, code, current output and error msgs in your Q and then we can help you. You at least have input and required output, so... you're half-way there. Good luck.

Comment: Yes - I see - I realy have no clue where to start I have not done anything like this before - But thanks for ur reply

Comment: That's not much help - but I 'll see what I can google .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v q="\"" '/FamilyType/{f=1} 
    f && /userName|serviceList|hostList|portNumber/
                   {sub(":","1=",$1); 
                    print $1 q $3 q
                   } 
           /port:/{f=0;print ""}' file

userName1="MATT_HANS"
serviceList1="H2O"
hostList1="159.220.108.80"
portNumber1="8149"

userName1="Geroge_lucas"
serviceList1="WWW"
hostList1="159.220.108.70"
portNumber1="8166"
```

ps. your hostList has ":" sign, this converts everything to "=" sign.  If not a typo you need to handle it specifically but I don't see a need for it.

UPDATE: set an incremental counter for the variable suffix.

```
$ awk -v q="\"" '/FamilyType/{f=1;c++} 
  f && /userName|serviceList|hostList|portNumber/
                             {sub(":",c"=",$1); 
                              print $1 q $3 q
                             } 
                      /port:/{f=0;print ""}' file

userName1="MATT_HANS"
serviceList1="H2O"
hostList1="159.220.108.80"
portNumber1="8149"

userName2="Geroge_lucas"
serviceList2="WWW"
hostList2="159.220.108.70"
portNumber2="8166"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your command works with above input. In my file I have leading spaces before the variables so I get a lot of other data. Can u get rid fo leading spaces?  Not sure why it doe snot work saisnt my file

Comment: also The second output of the variable should be assigned to 2? not one Otherwise thhey get overwritten

Comment: Make sure your input/output represents your actual data (albeit simplified).

Comment: see the update, leading spaces should not matter.

Comment: Thx - Still not working for my input -  have to create another question with my input -- Just not working for some reasoon against my file